# MongoDB : filter empty fields after projection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some problem to obtain good results after a projection. Indeed, hereunder my "toy" database (only 2 documents) :

```
{
  "file_name": "Running_2013-03-31T19_31_49",
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "product_name": "Suunto Ambit",
      "time_created": "2013-03-31 19:08:56"
    },
    {
      "type": "record",
      "heart_rate": 94,
      "position_lat": 47.35368099063635,
      "position_long": 0.8127570245414972,
      "timestamp": "2013-03-31 17:31:49"
    },
    {
      "type": "record",
      "heart_rate": 94,
      "position_lat": 47.353697000071406,
      "position_long": 0.8127430267632008,
      "timestamp": "2013-03-31 17:31:50"
    },
    {
      "type": "session",
      "avg_heart_rate": 169,
      "description": "Course.",
      "event": "session",
      "event_type": "stop",
      "max_heart_rate": 182,
      "min_heart_rate": 93,
      "sport": "running",
      "start_time": "2013-03-31 17:31:49",
      "time_in_hr_zone": [
        13.0,
        27.0,
        65.0,
        4145.0,
        1579.0
      ],
      "timestamp": "2013-03-31 19:08:56",
      "total_ascent": 81,
      "total_calories": 1454,
      "total_descent": 62,
      "total_distance": 18380.0,
      "total_elapsed_time": 5827.93,
      "total_training_effect": 5.0
    }
  ],
  "hrv": [
    0.121,
    0.626,
    0.62,
    0.628,
    0.336
  ]
}
{
  "file_name": "Running_2014-03-13T12_00_00",
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "activity",
      "product_name": "Suunto Ambit",
      "time_created": "2013-03-13 12:00:00"
    },
    {
      "type": "record",
      "heart_rate": 12,
      "position_lat": 47.35368099063635,
      "position_long": 0.8127570245414972,
      "timestamp": "2013-03-31 17:31:49"
    },
    {
      "type": "record",
      "heart_rate": 12,
      "position_lat": 47.353697000071406,
      "position_long": 0.8127430267632008,
      "timestamp": "2013-03-31 17:31:50"
    },
    {
      "type": "session",
      "avg_heart_rate": 70,
      "description": "Course.",
      "event": "session",
      "event_type": "stop",
      "max_heart_rate": 100,
      "min_heart_rate": 60,
      "sport": "running",
      "start_time": "2013-03-31 17:31:49",
      "time_in_hr_zone": [
        53.0,
        17.0,
        69.0,
        445.0,
        157.0
      ],
      "timestamp": "2013-03-31 19:08:56",
      "total_ascent": 21,
      "total_calories": 2100,
      "total_descent": 21,
      "total_distance": 8560.0,
      "total_elapsed_time": 3245,
      "total_training_effect": 5.0
    }
  ],
  "hrv": [
    0.213,
    0.314,
    0.125,
    0.314,
    0.211
  ]
}
```

I want to extract only 3 fields (**time_created**, **avg_heart_rate** and **sport**) from all the documents. For this, I made :

```
db.fit_json.find({}, {"_id": 0, "data.time_created": 1, "data.sport": 1, "data.avg_heart_rate": 1})
```

The problem is I have empty fields in the answer :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "time_created" : "2013-03-31 19:08:56"
        }, 
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {
            "avg_heart_rate" : 169,
            "sport" : "running"
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "time_created" : "2013-03-13 12:00:00"
        }, 
        {}, 
        {}, 
        {
            "avg_heart_rate" : 70,
            "sport" : "running"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to have this kind of result without empty fields:

```
{ { "time_created" : "2013-03-31 19:08:56" }, { "avg_heart_rate" : 169}, { "sport" : "running" } }
{ { "time_created" : "2013-03-13 12:00:00" }, { "avg_heart_rate" : 70}, { "sport" : "running" } }
```

Do you have an idea ?

Regards.

rmarion37

**2021/02/16 : EDIT**

I tried an other solution for cancelling the empty "json object" of the previous test :

```
db.getCollection('fit_json').aggregate({$addFields: {"time_created": "$data.time_created", "avg_heart_rate": "$data.avg_heart_rate"}}, {$project: {"_id": 0, "time_created": 1, "avg_heart_rate": 1}}).pretty()
```

To obtain :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "time_created" : [ 
        "2013-03-31 19:08:56"
    ],
    "sport" : [ 
        "running"
    ],
    "avg_heart_rate" : [ 
        169
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "time_created" : [ 
        "2013-03-13 12:00:00"
    ],
    "sport" : [ 
        "running"
    ],
    "avg_heart_rate" : [ 
        70
    ]
}
```

I used *$AddFields* to copy the datas I want to the root of the json-tree and select them by *$project*.
It's better but the values are now into list ([]).
My aim is to have :

```
{ { "time_created" : "2013-03-31 19:08:56" }, { "avg_heart_rate" : 169}, { "sport" : "running" } }
{ { "time_created" : "2013-03-13 12:00:00" }, { "avg_heart_rate" : 70}, { "sport" : "running" } }
```

Comment: Your DB example has only one document. Projection shows only 3 values from `data` array: time_created ; sport and avg_heart_rate. Only first and last elements into array has at least one of the fields. That's why other are empty.

Comment: Thanks for your request. Yes it's an example with only 1 document. In my original post, the result of the query was done on a collection with 2 documents (it's why, there is 2 lines result). I would like to do not have empty fields because it's a problem to make a Pandas dataframe with this structure of result. How is possible to generate an result without empty fields ?

Comment: Why do you have so many fields in the sample data? Remove all irrelevant ones.

Comment: Your last code block shows invalid code as well.

Comment: All the fields are relevant. I need all these information fields. The last code is the expected result I would like to obtain after the Mongodb query. Indeed I would to obtain a result without empty {}.

Comment: I found may be something. Is possible to use $filter command ?

Comment: The ""last code" you expect is not valid json. In your sample data, there is no 12:00:00 date. In sample provided there is only one document although you specify there are two. Also you may want to remove all fields which are irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: I uptade my first post to copy my "toy" database (With 2 documents). I found a better solution (just have a look to the edit in the original post) but it's not the definitive one !!! May be you can help me to definitely solve my problem !!!